# Handling Many-to-Many Relationship Duplicates in Power BI Visualization

Tags: powerbi, relationship, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Good morning, I wanted to create a visualization in Power BI between two tables, "FMapa" and "DRegiaoAdministrativa," using the columns RA (Administrative Region) and Bairro (Neighborhood). However, in the "DRegiaoAdministrativa" table, there are unique values that are not present in the "FMapa" table. I want to display these values that are not present in the "FMapa" table. When I try to do this using a many-to-many relationship between the tables, I end up with duplicated values. What should I do?

[image: 1]

I tried using the many-to-many relationship to filter the rows, but encountered this error. I attempted to utilize the unique columns from the 'DRegiaoAdministrativa' table, but it didn't work as expected. Instead, it created a null row with all the neighborhoods instead of listing them individually. What I desire is to have a table with neighborhoods that have values and the neighborhoods without values show as 0.

[image: 1]
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

The many to many relationship in power bi is discouraged to use because of this strange behaviour that can happen.

try to create a bridge table that have the PK of the two tables and connect them through the bridge...it will be many to one in both sides, see if it's the expected behaviour.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the response. I'm not sure if I did exactly what you told me, but I tried using the one-to-many, which was the only one for RA and Bairro. Could you please take a look at my table and come up with a strategy to avoid this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: so, you must try to create an other table, wich will contains the ID of the table A and the ID of the table B, using this table you can make the relationship with the table A using the id of table A and with table B using the id of table B